# Connect two devices with ethernet

Tags: ethernet, smb, connection-sharing, boxee

I have a MacBook Pro and I'm going to buy a [Boxee Box](http://www.boxee.tv/).

I have access to wireless internet, but it's slow and out of my control.

So my question is, what is the best way for both devices to get internet access, and the Boxee Box to get SMB access to the Mac, when only the Mac is connected to the wireless internet?

I'm thinking an ethernet cable from the Boxee Box to my Mac, and connection sharing on my Mac. Can you explain the setup, is there any configuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With modern macs, this should work as you describe it. You can just plug in your Boxee Box to the Mac, and setup the internet sharing on it. No need for a crossover cable anymore, most network card detect this automatically. If you should run into any trouble with the setup explained below, you should go out and buy a crossover cable, but i'd start without out:

- Open System Preferences, Sharing, Internet Connection Sharing
- Then select "Share your connection from AirPort" with Too Computer using "Ethernet"
- plug in your Boxee
- MacOS will assign it a IP via DHCP and it should be online automagically.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

es, but because you're connecting two computers directly together you will very likely need a "cross-over ethernet cable."

The cross-over (or "x-over") ethernet cable has a slightly different set of connections internally that normally aren't needed between a computer and a router.

However, the best way is to get a small 5-port (or 8-port because these often cost only a few dollars extra) ethernet switch and connecting one of its ports to your internet router (your "Boxee Box" I presume) with a cross-over cable (with newer ethernet switches you often don't need this as they auto-sense the need for cross-over and will adjust accordingly), then connecting all your computers to that little ethernet switch.

The problem with connection sharing is you become dependent on having that connection sharing machine always being available when you need it, which may not be as convenient (although that solution will work too).